# Will I get the mutual fund/etf monthly distributions from the first month I invest in?

Tags: etf, mutual-funds, online-trading, etn

If a mutual fund or the etf gives distributions on a monthly basis, Will I get the distributions from the first month I invest in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but note that it's not "free money". All else being equal, the value of the ETF will drop by the amount of the dividend since it's a reduction in the fund's net assets. So If you pay $100 per unit for one unit of a fund and it pays a $5 dividend the next day, you'll then have $5 in cash and a $95 unit of the ETF.

Dividends do not increase wealth; they are just a way to get cash to the owners of the ETF without forcing them to sell their shares.

Answer (score 6):

If you own an ETF, mutual fund or stock when the stock goes ex-dividend, you'll receive the dividend/distribution on the Pay Date.

Comment: I think you mean if you own it *before* the ex-dividend date.